# Open system call with parameter 0 as a flag

Tags: c, call, system

Im trying to open a device file (but the question is mainly for a general file) and it's working with the next line

```
fd = open(path,0);
```

but failed with the following line

```
fd = open(path,O_RDONLY,0777)
```

(even without the mode 0777)
I just dont understand what is the meaning of puting 0 instead of a flag and why its working.

Answer (score 2):

[The POSIX specifications for `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) require that exactly one of the defined constants `O_EXEC`, `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDWR`, or `O_SEARCH` be included in the flags, but they do not specify the *values* of these constants.  Indeed, they note in the rationale that "in historical implementations the value of `O_RDONLY` is zero."  On such an implementation, specifying flags as 0 is equivalent to specifying (only) `O_RDONLY`.

POSIX's use of the term "historical" should not be taken as suggesting that it is rare for `O_RDONLY` to have the value 0; on the contrary, it is quite common in present-day implementations.  Nevertheless, you should not specify the flags as 0 when you mean `O_RDONLY`, as that leaves your code open to breakage on systems with different definitions of the flag constants.

If you indeed can open with flags given as 0 but not with flags given as `O_RDONLY` (which seems doubtful), then it must be the case that `O_RDONLY` has a value different from 0 in your implementation.  It may then be that one of the other members of the mandatory constant group has value 0, and that you can open the target file in the corresponding mode -- for example, maybe the path designates a directory, and it is `O_SEARCH` that has value 0.  Otherwise, you are eliciting undefined behavior from `open()`. UB does not have to manifest as returning an error indicator, and if it happens not to do so then that tells you nothing.

---

Addendum: given that `open(path, O_RDONLY)` fails for you (as indicated by returning -1), it would be worthwhile to probe the reason for the error by examining `errno`, or, better, by printing a diagnostic via `perror()`.